# How to set underscore with the selected menu item in BottomNavigationView

Tags: java, android

I am using MaterialDesign BottomNavigationView.
How to set the underscore with the selected menu item in BottomNavigationView?
Thanks for the response!

[BottomNavigationView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oL4X.png)

Comment: I guess an easy and dumb way is to change the *image:src* when you switch to that View.

Comment: I tried, but the line in the middle between the end of the screen and the icon

Comment: What English is this bro. I cant understand u.